# Two classes of subgroups of order 24 in a simple group of order 168

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

In a [paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869370900189/1-s2.0-0021869370900189-main.pdf?_tid=c1a38d2a-0a36-11e7-9d07-00000aacb360&acdnat=1489661775_9ab2b8bca4606d3b80a6f47633ebc5f6) that I am reading, the author said that there exists a simple group of order 168 and it is known to have two distinct conjugacy classe of subgroups of order 24.

My question: Are they probably referring to $PSL(3,2)$? If so, what are the the subgroups of order 24 explicitly.

Comment: Yes, it is $PSL(3,2)\simeq PSL(2,7)$. It is a non-obvious but somewhat standard exercise to prove that any simple group of order $168$ is isomorphic to the subgroup of $A_8$ that you get from a study of the action of $PSL(2,7)$ on the projective line $\Bbb{P}^1(\Bbb{F}_7)$.

Comment: Agreed, but I used to find it easier to construct the two classes of $S_4$s, and then use these to provide the projective plane over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Answer (score 3):

As there is just one simple group of order 168, they are, and it is more easily seen to be $\text{GL}(3,2)$.

You will get one class of subgroups isomorphic to $S_4$ by taking the block matrices
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
A & 0\\
v&1\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
where the $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ is of course non-singular.

These stabilise a [whatever] in the projective plane, and as I recall it the other class of $S_4$'s stabilise a [dual whatever].

Comment: The author says that there is two distinct conjugacy classes of subgroups of order 24 which are interchanged by an outer automorphism.

Comment: @RMaharaj I hazard a guess that the outer automorphism in question sends a 3x3 matrix $A$ to $(A^t)^{-1}$.

Comment: The automorphism comes from the swap of points/lines, so Yes.